# get ALL elements from set in random order

Tags: java, set, shuffle

I need to get all elements from set in random order. I found some solutions, however i would like to find the best and the fastest.
Is there any analogue for Collections.shuffle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a direct analogue, because there's no order on sets, so shuffling has no semantics for the set. If you want to get the elements in different orders a number of times, you need to convert the Set to a list (which you know has no duplicates because it just came from a Set) and shuffle it.

```
List<Elem> withAnOrdering = new ArrayList<>(fromMySetOfElem);
for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)
{
     Collections.shuffle(withAnOrdering);
     //Do something with the ordering

}
```